# BIRT- format parameter

Tags: eclipse, parameters, birt

I am using Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.3.2.v20140211-1400 Build 4.3.2.v20140211-1526 against Sybase ASE.  I want the user prompt for two date parameters to format as 7-30-14.  Currently the default is showing 2014-7-30.

Per recommendations from other postings I chose Properties for the Parameter from the Eclipse Outline view.  In the Edit Properties under Display As it shows the Custom Format I selected M/d/yy and the Preview shows 7/30/14.  However, when I run the report it still requires me to enter it as yyyy-mm-dd and errors out with a bad date any other way.

Am I missing something else?
Here is the xml for the parameters

```
<parameters>
    <scalar-parameter name="report_dt" id="85">
        <text-property name="promptText">Enter Date as MM/dd/yy</text-property>
        <property name="valueType">static</property>
        <property name="isRequired">true</property>
        <property name="dataType">date</property>
        <property name="distinct">true</property>            
        <simple-property-list name="defaultValue">
            <value type="javascript">params["end_dt"].value</value>
        </simple-property-list>
        <list-property name="selectionList"/>
        <property name="paramType">simple</property>
        <property name="controlType">text-box</property>
        <structure name="format">
            <property name="category">Custom</property>
            <property name="pattern">M/d/yy</property>
        </structure>
    </scalar-parameter>
    <scalar-parameter name="end_dt" id="88">
        <text-property name="promptText">Enter the end of the range.  By default this will be the same as the start date</text-property>
        <property name="valueType">static</property>
        <property name="isRequired">true</property>
        <property name="dataType">date</property>
        <property name="distinct">true</property>
        <simple-property-list name="defaultValue">
            <value type="javascript">params["report_dt"].value</value>
        </simple-property-list>
        <list-property name="selectionList"/>
        <property name="paramType">simple</property>
        <property name="controlType">text-box</property>
        <structure name="format">
            <property name="category">Custom</property>
            <property name="pattern">M/d/yy</property>
        </structure>
    </scalar-parameter>
</parameters>
```

Comment: The same is working for me with the format M/d/yy you specified. So i believe the issue is due to the way this parameter is used in your dataset: may be the dataset parameter is declared as a string forcing a conversion of the date, or something like that.

Comment: the third property listed for both parameters is set 'dataType = date'.  Is there somewhere else that might reset that to a string?  I checked the properties for both in the GUI interface Properties and both are set as java.util.Date.  Or they might be java.sql.Date - I don't recall offhand but they are both set to date values.

Comment: Please notice i was talking about the datatype of dataset parameters, not report parameters. May be you could join a simple report showing the issue based on the sample database, i would have a look

Comment: Here is the query I wrote  'SELECT DISTINCT S.EARN_TYPE, SUM(POSTS_CNT) AS "Total Assigned"
  FROM TABLE_A AS W, TABLE_B AS S
  WHERE W.EARNTYPE_CD = S.EARNTYPE_CD AND WORK_DT BETWEEN $P{report_dt} AND $P{end_dt}
  GROUP BY S.EARN_TYPE'                                                             WORK_DT is a SYBASE datetime value